# How to translate 哪有农村热闹？

Tags: meaning-in-context

北京城里禁止随便放鞭炮，城里人过春节越来越简单， **哪有农村热闹**？

I don't understand the last part of this sentence, marked in bold. I guess it's a rhetorical question?

My attempt:

*Beijing City banned setting off fireworks, so the city dwellers' celebration of the Spring Festival has become more and more simple. **The city is not as lively as the countryside?***

I can provide more of the dialogue if necessary.

Comment: What place could be more lively than contryside?

Comment: How could it be more lively than contryside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a rhetorical question, the emphasis is on the lively and noisy fashion the village dwellers can celebrate compared to Beijingers. It is a good way to contrast difference. I would translate it (second sentence only) as `'How can you compare that to the lively manner of celebration in the countryside!'`

PS. My English is not the best, native speakers can put it right, but I think the idea is clear.